# How to do double for loop to generate keep list in SAS?

Tags: for-loop, sas

I have a very large dataset with over 1000 columns, with column names formatted like this:

```
WORLDDATA.table2_usa_2017_population
WORLDDATA.table2_japan_2017_gnp
```

I only need to keep a subset of these parameters for a select few countries. I specify the custom lists:

```
%let list1 = usa canada uk japan southafrica;
%let list2 = population crimerate gnp;
```

How do I do a double for loop like so:

```
param_list = []
for (i in list1) {
  for (j in list2) {
     param_name = WORLDDATA.table2_{list1[i]}_2017_{list2[j]}
     param_list.append(param_name)
  }
}
```

such that I can use param_list in

```
data final_dataset;
  set WORLDDATA.table2;
  keep {param_list};
run;
```

Thank you!

Comment: SAS data steps use `DO` loops and SAS macro code uses `%DO` loops.  Show what you have tried.

Comment: In SAS 9.4 you could also try PROC LUA

Comment: How many rows in the very large data set? What does every row correspond to?

Comment: Is WORLDDATA a library name or a table name? You state data set but it smells like a libname.

Comment: WORLDDATA is too long to use as a libref and variable names cannot contain a period.

Answer (score 0):

Your original data set has *data items* `country` and `topic` encoded into the column name (*metadata*) you will probably need to transpose the data for use in SAS procedure steps that would use statements such as `where`, `by` and `class`.

`Proc TRANSPOSE` can pivot data from wide to tall and the output will have a column named `_NAME_` which can be used in a `where=(where-statement)` option on the output data set.  Th *where-statement* would be a regex expression having your lists specified as alternation (`|`) items in a group (such as `(item-1|...|item-N)`).  The regex engine would perform the implicit outer join that the nested loop in the question pseudo code does.  The regex pattern would use the /ix modifiers in order to have a pattern formatted for human readability that also ignores case.

In order to have `Proc TRANSPOSE` pivot each row of a data set, the data set needs to have row key (a variable or variables in combination) that are distinct from row to row.

Untested example:

```
proc transpose data=have_wide out=want_subset_categorical (where=(
  prxmatch("(?ix)/
    table2_
      %sysfunc(translate(&LIST1.,|,%str( ))   (?# list 1 spaces converted to | ors )
    _2017_
      %sysfunc(translate(&LIST2.,|,%str( ))   (?# list 2 spaces converted to | ors )

  /",_name_)
));
  by <row-key>;
run;
```